# CSS vertical height (vh) value varies from desktop to mobile? (jQuery-Mobile framework)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

So I have a div that contains varying content depending on buttons that are clicked. **Since I want this div to be contained within a segment of the page, I'm using the CSS vertical height (vh) property to set the div height.** And currently I'm working on a form that I'm adjusting the div's vh value for so that the whole form is visible via scrolling.

**However, I've noticed that the height that I'm ending up with is different between a desktop browser and a mobile browser** (specifically Chrome Desktop and Safari Mobile at the moment). **For some reason there's a lot more space being created in the desktop version than in the mobile version**, and I figure this could be attributed to the much larger screen space on the monitor versus the tablet, but I thought that using CSS vh would account for this?

If not, how should I be adjusting div height to match across desktop and mobile?

Comment: vertical height is currently only supported in ie9.  although it seems to work in chrome (i have tried it) it does not seem to work in mobile browsers (i have tried it)

Comment: is there a `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />` in the `<head>`? (or `@viewport {width: device-width;}` in CSS)

Comment: 100vh = the height of the viewport. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using a max-height for that div, or perhaps manually setting the height in your css and giving it an `overflow: scroll`

for mobile you will need a media query, in chrome console, there is a little button at the top left that looks like a phone. Click it and select the device you want to apply css to. From there you can fiddle around until you get what you like. Then in your css you do a media query like this

```
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
...your css

}
```

Comment: The above query is for an iphone 5 ;)

Comment: I finally got this working, thank you. I didn't realize at first that this was essentially a wrapper for individual css queries so I was trying to include the class name that I was modifying into the query. Only later did I realize that you take ALL of the CSS in it's usual format and put it into this wrapper.

Comment: sorry, maybe i should have been more explicit, but I'm glad it all worked out! :)